# Saving custom form fields

Tags: plugins, php, forms

I am creating a plugin. So far I have created a menu and a page containing the form. I want to save these form fields for any user with 'Doctors' role. I think it should be saved under wp_usermeta table.  How I can save these fields for a user? Here is my code..

```
add_menu_page('Loyalty','Loyalty Programs', 'doctors', 'loyalty-programs', 'create_loyalty');
function create_loyalty(){
     <div class="section panel">
     <h1>Loyalty Program Settings</h1>
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
     Enable Loyalty Program : <input type="checkbox" name="enable" class="checkbox">
     Set PayBack :<input type="text" name="cashback" id="cash_back" class="payback" />
     CashBack Validity :<input type="text" name="validity" id="payback_validity"       class="validity" />
     <p class="submit">  
            <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>
     </p>  
    </form>
     </div>

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what 'form settings' are we talking about?

Comment: I need to save the above form fields for each users with the role doctors.sorry I miss used the term form settings here..